# Qual è il significato di "bandire" in queste espressioni?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Ho scoperto questo [sito web](http://www.italiano-online.it/verbi-Bconprep.html) che ho trovato molto utile per imparare le preposizioni che accompagnano alcuni verbi italiani. Come esempi con il verbo "bandire" si trovano queste espressioni che non riesco a capire bene:

> - Bandire dal cuore.
> - Bandire dai propri ricordi.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "bandire" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può avere il senso figurato di "allontanare". Quindi, il significato sarebbe "allontanare dal cuore" e "allontanare dai propri ricordi"? Potreste spiegarmi un po' meglio il senso di queste espressioni facendo qualche esempio per illustrarne l'uso?

Comment: Bandire i brutti ricordi  dalla mia vita, bandire la tristezza  dai miei pensieri, etc... nel senso di allontanare, scacciare. È un uso abbastanza comune di sapore letterario.

Comment: Anticamente "bandire" significava "esiliare" qualcuno, cacciarlo via dalla città. Per questo, nel senso figurato significa "allontanare".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il senso proprio di "bandire" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bandire/) è quello di "mettere un bando", ossia affiggere dei manifesti pubblici in un posto per annunciare qualcosa. Tutt'oggi si usa dire che un ente ha "bandito" una gara pubblica, per esempio per una qualche fornitura (anche se in genere oggi le cose passano da Internet).

Nel significato esteso, "bandire" significa dichiarare pubblicamente che qualcuno è un criminale, mettendo dei manifesti che per esempio annunciano la disponibilità di una taglia per chi assicurerà il criminale alla giustizia (sono famosi i manifesti "Wanted" dei film western). Per lo stesso motivo il criminale stesso è detto "bandito". Il bandito è quindi invitato ad allontanarsi dalla comunità che l'ha bandito e nella quale evidentemente non è gradito né al sicuro. Questo spiega il senso che hai trovato: si può quindi dire che "il tale brigante è stato bandito dalla tale contea".

Dunque nelle espressioni che hai trovato il significato di "allontanare" è quello di "cacciare via come persona non gradita, come criminale o come qualcuno che ti ha fatto del male". Il significato è naturalmente piuttosto emotivamente carico: si può (tentare di) bandire una persona dal proprio cuore (o dal proprio ricordo, che è quasi la stessa cosa: il cuore è sede di ricordi e sentimenti); significa che quella persona, della quale magari ci si è innamorati, è stata riconosciuta in modo negativo (perché ci ha ferito o rifiutato) e quindi si desidera perderne il ricordo.